# How to get rid of this element or change its color?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to get rid of the following element or change its color if it's possible  - it's not a border, it's a background image. It's code looks like that:

```
.col-2cl .main-inner {
    background: url(img/sidebar/s-right-s1.png) repeat-y right 0;
    padding-right: 340px;
}
```

My question is, how can I get rid of this element? I'm trying to completely remove it on dark version of my website, but I just can't - I feel like I've tried everything (`background: none;`, etc). I can't completely delete the file because I need it on light version of my website. My site:

Comment: `display: none;`?

Comment: It will hide most of my site if I use display:none on that element.

Comment: Please upload your images to stack imgur. You have enough reputation to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any new value you will assign for `.col-2cl .main-inner` will hide that image.

In your case, you should show dark mod or at least define how dark mode is implemented. Is it changing attributes or just changing class names?

if it is changing class names, you should define your css code according to that change, for example, let assume in dark mode, you added the new class name to any div tag parent of `.main-inner` as `.dark-mode`.

Then, you can use the following code:

```
div:not(.dark-mode) .main-inner{ background: rgba(252, 252, 252, 0) !important; }
```

this code will make fully transparent of that section only when it is not on dark-mode.

But as I described you need to understand how dark mode changes your website structure. Maybe, it is not adding new classes but changing the all CSS file. Then you just need to edit that specific files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```css
.col-2cl .main-inner {
display: none; // In case it will not work, you can try to add !important before the semicolon.
}
```

or change the background property with

```css
.col-2cl .main-inner {
background: url(new_background_image.jpg) repeat-y right 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: It looks like silencesys answer would do it. I looked at your source and you have a ton of external style sheets, So I am suspicious that if silencesys solution doesn't work then you may be overwriting the style in a later loading style sheet. Also note you provided your url, and the path to the image, and putting them together ( https://gameshunt.pl/img/sidebar/s-right-s1.png ) results in file not found, that further makes me suspicious that the image is styled in a later loading style sheet.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these suggestions work - I've tried them before. I can't use display:none; on the whole element because it will hide posts, sidebars etc as well. Also, I need this element on my normal website - I need to hide it just on dark mode (for now it's visible only for administrators). 

Second option is not good as well - it just doesn't work. 

@SteveLage 

The path seems suspisious to me too, but it was coded that way by theme developer. It somehow works...

Comment: This code should work:
```css
.col-2cl .main-inner {
    background: none !important;
}
```
I've tried to put it in the style block to the head of the page and it worked.

The picture is located at https://gameshunt.pl/wp-content/themes/writeup/img/sidebar/s-right-s1.png, it is a wordpress site. :)